# Google Spanner - Java Mutation - Delete rows with subset of composite key values

Tags: java, partial, composite-primary-key, google-cloud-spanner, mutation

I have a requirement where I need to delete rows based on the subset of composite keys via mutation.

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE FOO
(KEY1 INT64, KEY2 INT64, KEY3 INT64, VALUE STRING(100))
PRIMARY KEY (KEY1, KEY2, KEY3)
```

However I need a mutation that should delete all rows matching KEY1 and KEY2 ignoring KEY3 value. I am trying to achieve with Mutation and I get this error

My Code:

```
Mutation.delete("FOO",
            KeySet.newBuilder().
                    addKey(Key.of(key1Value,
                            key2Value))
                    .build())
```

Error:

> com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerException: FAILED_PRECONDITION:
> io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Wrong number of
> key parts for FOO. Expected: 3. Got: ["943598","213122"]

I have links for all composite keys but not a subset of them: [Deleting row using composite key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001488/deleting-row-using-composite-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `KeySet.prefixRange(..)` for this:

```java
Mutation.delete("my-table", KeySet.prefixRange(Key.of(key1Value, key2Value)));
```

Comment: Now, how do you delete the mutation? Using com.google.cloud.spanner.DatabaseClient?

Comment: Yes, use the `com.google.cloud.spanner.DatabaseClient#write(Iterable<Mutation>)` method. See here for an example: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/samples/spanner-insert-data#code-sample